# WebRequest doesnt send passed CookieContianer that was made from a CookieCollection

Tags: c#, json, cookies, request, cookiecontainer

I made a server that listen to a port for POST requests.
It handles a JSON and it deserializes to a class containing some strings and a CookieCollection

All correct there, but when I pass the CookieCollection to a CookieContainer and use that container on a request it is sending without the cookies.

Json example:

```
"loginContainer":[
  {
     "Comment":"",
     "CommentUri":null,
     "HttpOnly":true,
     "Discard":false,
     "Domain":"removed",
     "Expired":false,
     "Expires":"2026-07-02T12:42:43+02:00",
     "Name":"locale",
     "Path":"/",
     "Port":"",
     "Secure":false,
     "TimeStamp":"2021-07-03T12:42:14.8645637+02:00",
     "Value":"removed",
     "Version":0
  }
```

Collection to CookieContainer:

```
CookieContainer loginContainer = new CookieContainer();

foreach (Cookie cookie in root.LoginContainer)
{
     Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + " " + cookie.Value);
     loginContainer.Add(cookie);
}
```

Request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

request.CookieContainer = loginContainer;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
     listLabels.Add(ms.ToArray(), labels.Phrase);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by looping the CookieCollection and inserting inside the CookieContainer a new made Cookie with the CookieCollection values, not the one from the CookieCollection.

```
foreach (Cookie cookie in root.LoginContainer)
{
    loginContainer.Add(new Cookie() { Name = cookie.Name, Value = cookie.Value, Path = cookie.Path, Domain = cookie.Domain });
}
```